# Appcelerator titanium Android push notification GCM failure?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, push, appcelerator

i've setup push notification for Android and IOS in new project in Appcelerator studio , the IOS working fine , but the android not , my issue is the android devices token is successfully taken and registered but when i send a push from Appcelerator studio IOS success when Android failed.

[image]

> I've enabled this API's in google developer console .

[image]

> and created API key :

[image]

> and i used the API key in Appcelerator ASC :

[image]

i don't understand why i can take the Android device token but i am not able to send push notification ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution the document of appcelerator is not updated yet

so here what you have to do

try the following sample code for devices registration :

https://gist.github.com/MotiurRahman/68bb7aad307901805b5f

Then Configuring push services for Android devices :

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Configuring_push_services-section-37551713_Configuringpushservices-ConfiguringpushservicesforAndroiddevices

With  Firebase  WEB API KEY 
and project ID

https://console.firebase.google.com/?pli=1

Get project_number (as Sender ID ) from  JSON file and Web API KEY( as GCM API key ) from your firebase console.Now configure your dashboard for push notification

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Sending_and_Scheduling_Push_Notifications

Comment: What are the values we use now? The Appcelerator ACS now asks for Server key and Sender ID. I keep getting a "Failed" error. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743333/appcelerator-titanium-cannot-send-push-notification-to-android

Comment: I also have a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757524/appcelerator-titanium-getting-android-credentials-to-push-notifications