# Appcelerator: Android push notifications not being pushed to devices

Tags: android, push-notification, appcelerator, arrowdb

I am using Appcelerator cloud services for push notifications. The app is set up correctly on bot iOS and Android, and iOS push notifications are appearing on the device. However, on Android, no notifications are showing up.

On the Android side, I have verified that the Android device is subscribed to the notifications by reviewing the list of devices registered on the website.

In the android push tab I have verified that the API Key is identical to the API key in the credentials list on the Google API page, and the Sender ID is the same as Project Number listed on the Project Settings page.

I have followed the answer on this page: [Appcelerator titanium Android push notification GCM failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025141/appcelerator-titanium-android-push-notification-gcm-failure)

I am not sure what more to try, does anyone have any tutorials, or ideas on what to try to figure out where the failure point is?

**UPDATE:**
I found that I can see the error by looking at the details of the push. I get the following error:

```
Exception Type: GCM; Error Code: 3103; Error Message: RegistrationId(s) is null or empty; Catched Exception: argument cannot be null
```

I am not sure what that means, but that field is not available on the push form, so I am still at a loss at what to do.

UPDATE 2: 
I grabbed another Android device and ran the app on it. (I had a suspision that the above error was due to the first device not registering for the push correctly)

On the second device the notification still didn't come through, however, there are now no errors in the website log. It shows success for both iOS and Android. Back to square one.