# Appcelerator/ Titanium: Cannot send push notification to Android

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-arrow

I want to be able to send push notifications using Titanium and Arrow Push on Android.

I have followed the instructions here:

[Configuring Push Services](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Configuring_push_services)

[Subscribing to push notifications](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Subscribing_to_push_notifications)

[Modules.CloudPush](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.CloudPush)

My simple code looks as follows:

```
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
var deviceToken = null;
    
// Works fine
CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
    success: function () {
        deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
        alert('deviceToken: ' + deviceToken);
        subscribeToChannel();
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Failed to register for push notifications! ' + e.error);
    }
});
    
// Never runs!!!
CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function (evt) {
    Ti.API.info('New notification!');
    alert("Notification received: " + evt.payload);
});

// Works fine
function subscribeToChannel () {
    Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribeToken({
        device_token: deviceToken,
        channel: 'general',
        type: Ti.Platform.name
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            alert('Subscribed');
        } else {
            alert('Error:\n' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
}
```

Most of the above code is similar to the docs. The subscription aspect of the code seems to works perfectly fine, as the user's device also appears in the devices section of the Appcelerator Dashboard.

However when it comes to **sending** a notification, from the Appcelerator Dashboard, the word "Failure" appears next to my Android device.

[image: Error on push notifications]

The full error message when highlighting the "?" icon is as follows:

> Exception Type: GCM; Error Code: 3103; Error Message:
> RegistrationId(s) is null or empty; Catched Exception: argument cannot
> be null

I looked this error up on http://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/guide/troubleshooting and all it says is:

> The GCM client provided a null or empty registration ID. This error is
> uncommon if you are using the Modules.CloudPush module.

Which isn't helpful.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug on Accelerator side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my code was fine. The credentials I was using however was incorrect. Please see my other related question here:

[Appcelerator/ Titanium: Getting Android credentials to push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757524/appcelerator-titanium-getting-android-credentials-to-push-notifications)

The docs are in need of updating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hardly an expert with push, but I compared what you have to what I have in one of my apps.

Pretty sure you need to send the deviceToken into the subscribeToChannel function.

Try changing this -

```
function subscribeToChannel () {
```

to this -

```
function subscribeToChannel (deviceToken) {
```

then add the token to the call here -

```
subscribeToChannel (deviceToken);
```

Let me know if that works for you.

-Jon

Comment: That's not the issue. The device token is a global variable is fine here. In fact it even subscribed fine as well as it's on the device list

Comment: I think the issue is where I got my credentials as the documentation seems out of date. Where did you get yours?

Comment: @YahyaUddin  This is a snip from the notes I took when I worked this out last year -

Create a Google API Project
The first step is creating a Google API project and enabling its GCM service. You also need to obtain a GCM sender ID and create a Google API server key.

create a new project from here :
https://console.developers.google.com/project

GO TO API Manager
Credentials - create API Key - copy it and paste it into the Arrow dashboard 
click hamburger menu - IAM & Admin
Settings - copy the project number - paste that into Arrow dashboard

Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Please look at my related question here to see what I did wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757524/appcelerator-titanium-getting-android-credentials-to-push-notifications . Thanks so much.

Comment: It seems that the Google changed some things around!

Comment: I posted the notes over there as well, looks like you were close, just create an API Key instead of an OAuth Client ID.

Answer (score 0):

On `subscribeToChannel()` function, you should use `type : 'gcm'` instead of `type: Ti.Platform.name`

This is a commonJS module that I created for my Android push:

```
function ACSPush(_callback) {

    var debug_mode = true;
    var Cloud = require('ti.cloud');        
    var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
    CloudPush.enabled = true; 
    var deviceToken;

    CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
        success : function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
            if(debug_mode)
                Ti.API.info('Device Token: ' + e.deviceToken);
            deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
            if(Ti.App.Properties.getString("deviceToken") != deviceToken.toString()){
                defaultSubscribe();
            };
        },
        error : function deviceTokenError(e) {
            if(debug_mode)
                Ti.API.info('deviceTokenError.. :( ' + e.error);
        }
    });

    function defaultSubscribe() {
        Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribeToken({
            channel : 'MyChannel',
            device_token : deviceToken,
            type : 'gcm'
        }, function(e) {
            if(e.success) {
                if(debug_mode)
                    Ti.API.info("Success registerForPushNotifications");
                Ti.App.Properties.setString("deviceToken", deviceToken.toString());
            } else {
                if(debug_mode)
                    Ti.API.info('Error:\n' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
            };
        });
    };

    CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function(evt) {
        var payload = JSON.parse(evt.payload);
        if(debug_mode){
            Ti.API.info("Received a push notification\nPayload:\n" + JSON.stringify(evt.payload));
            Ti.API.info("payload: " + payload);
        };
        _callback(payload);
    });
    CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickLaunchedApp', function(evt) {
        if(debug_mode)
            Ti.API.info('Tray Click Launched App (app was not running)');
    });
    CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickFocusedApp', function(evt) {
        if(debug_mode)
            Ti.API.info('Tray Click Focused App (app was already running)');
    });

};

module.exports = ACSPush;
```

Obviously, you must first configure Android Push Service http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Configuring_push_services-section-src-37551713_Configuringpushservices-ConfiguringpushservicesforAndroiddevices

Comment: The type 'gcm' is not mentioned anywhere in the docs. None the less I tried it and it didn't change anything. The error is still there. I really think the issue is where I got my credentials. How did you get yours as the docs are really out of date,

Comment: You can find it on https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard. You have to create a Project (and you'll have the Sender ID), and then have to create a new Credential for App Android (this will be your API key)

Comment: Please see my related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757524/appcelerator-titanium-getting-android-credentials-to-push-notifications . Things have changed on both Appcelerator and google ends

Comment: It's really strange. I'm using it in different android app, and I have not changed this configuration for more than two years, and it still works correctly.

Comment: Perhaps google wants to keep backwards compatibility. Can you try with a new demo app?